# Get coordinates of a building with geocoding

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geocoding, openstreetmap

I want to get the coordinates of a building with geocoding. At the moment I use the GeoCoder class for android to get from the selected address the coordinates, but these are not corresponding to the edge of the building. OSM is containing these information for each building, but I do not know how to get these information with the GeoCoder class. Is there a possibility to use OSM with the geocoder class for android to get this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a little bit more complicated. First, OSM doesn't have for every address a building. And sometimes a building contains several addresses, or an address can belong to several buildings.

But as a first step you can use [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for geocoding to obtain the coordinates for a specific address. And afterwards pass these coordinates to the Overpass API and search for nearby buildings.

Example:

We are searching for the building for the address *Franzweg 4, Dresden*. The Nominatim query could look like this (assuming we want JSON output):

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Franzweg+4%2C+Dresden&addressdetails=1&format=json

It returns an exact match because the address exists in OSM's database. You can see that by looking at the address details, both *house_number* and *road* match. We even get a corresponding [way with ID 94892819](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/94892819) which has the [building](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3abuilding) tag and contains the coordinates of the building outline when [querying the API for the way ID](http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/94892819) (see the [API documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6)).

But as already stated not every address belongs to a building. For example when [searching for](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Huttenstra%C3%9Fe%2014,%20Dresden&addressdetails=1&format=json) *Huttenstraße 14, Dresden* we also get an exact result but the returned way [with ID 240398228](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/240398228) belongs to an *area*. This area contains a building which consequently belongs to this address. Nominatim also returns a bounding box, in this case *51.0508041381836,51.0514030456543,13.7778491973877,13.7796478271484*. We can use it for retrieving objects inside that area. If you don't have a local copy of OSM's database you can use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) with the following query:

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <query type="way">
    <has-kv k="building"/>
    <bbox-query e="13.7796478271484" n="51.0514030456543" s="51.0508041381836" w="13.7778491973877"/>
  </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton"/>
</osm-script>
```

This query [returns](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%3Cosm-script%20output=%22json%22%3E%20%3Cquery%20type=%22way%22%3E%20%3Chas-kv%20k=%22building%22/%3E%20%3Cbbox-query%20e=%2213.7796478271484%22%20n=%2251.0514030456543%22%20s=%2251.0508041381836%22%20w=%2213.7778491973877%22/%3E%20%3C/query%3E%20%3Cprint%20mode=%22body%22/%3E%20%3Crecurse%20type=%22down%22/%3E%20%3Cprint%20mode=%22skeleton%22/%3E%20%3C/osm-script%3E) all *ways* with the *buildings* tag in the given bounding box. You can use [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1bo) to visualize the result. As you can see, the bounding box contains more than one building but only one of them is inside the area. So you have to go through the coordinates of each of the building to see which one fits. Remember, one address *could* belong to multiple buildings, so there can be more than one single match.

Then there is also a third case where the address is a single [node](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). For example the result for [Striesener Straße 38b](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Striesener%20Stra%C3%9Fe%2038b,%20Dresden&addressdetails=1&format=json) returns the [node with ID 1615986605](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/node/1615986605). Here the *node* is actually a member of the building *way* so it is easy to determine the corresponding building. But this is not always the case, you might need to run another Overpass API query to determine nearby buildings and, again, see which one fits best.